# Android- Main Activity is not a concrete class

Tags: java, android

my main activity shows the following errors -

```
class MainActivity must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method OnConnectionSuspended(int) in ConnectionCallbacks
```

due to this method -

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
     GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
     View.OnClickListener{
```

so when I add `abstract` to the class declaration like this

```
public abstract class MainActivity
```

I get the following error in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

`com.myfork.myfork.MainActivity is not a concrete class`

here 
`android:name=".MainActivity"`

When I try to run after adding `abstract` I get the message the `unfortunately the app has stopped`

What could be the problem?

Comment: This question is essentially identical to yours.  Same problem, different interface: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733653/class-must-either-be-declared-abstract-or-implement-abstract-method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you implement an `interface` you should implement all its methods. In your case error says that you should implement `OnConnectionSuspended(int)` in your `MainActivity`. This is what you probably want to do..

Other option would be to make `MainActivity` `abstract`, but in this case you cannot instantiate it, i.e. you can't start it. In this case you will have to create other activity that will extend `MainActivity` and that activity will implement `OnConnectionSuspended(int)`.